# Nexmo Messaging API

Tags: laravel-5, vonage

I am working on an sms feature by the Nexmo package. i however ran into a difficulty that i cant solve.
I have the following code in my rooutes php

```
Route::get('/sms/send/{to}', function(\Nexmo\Client $nexmo, $to){

    $message = $nexmo->message()->send([
        'to' => '0725959830',
        'from' => '0791179389',
        'text' => 'Sending SMS from Laravel. Woohoo!'
    ]);
    Log::info('sent message: ' . $message['message-id']);
});
```

Then with this i get an error:

> **Target [Nexmo\Client\Credentials\CredentialsInterface] is not instantiable while building [Nexmo\Client].**

Any ideas please

Comment: @leggetter anything here?

Comment: anyone with an idea

Comment: Based on searching `is not instantiable while building` I'm reasonably sure this isn't a problem with the Nexmo library. It's likely a generic problem with the Laravel setup/config.